# Yii2: Не передается одно значение в модель

Tags: php, yii2

Я через миграцию добавил в таблицу одну колонку, `name`. В контроллере создаю модель, чтобы записать комментарии в нее из вьюхи.

Но вот что происходит, в случае где передается `text` параметр, то всё нормально добавляется в бд, но почему то name вообще не срабатывает. Я вардампил атрибуты которые приходят в модель, там всё что надо, кроме поля `name`. В POST всё приходит правильно, проверил.

Если я нагло пропишу в контроллере `$comments->name = "Своё значение";` - Оно запишется в БД. Из POST почему то нет. Comments наследуется от AR. Я уже борюсь час где-то, и не понимаю почему происходит так.

Вот код контроллера:

```
$comments = new Comment();
$comments->article_id = $_GET['id'];

    if($comments->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $comments->save();
        return $this->refresh();
    }
```

Код View:

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['class' =>"form-horizontal contact-form"]); ?>
                 <?= $form->field($comments, 'name')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Name'])->label(false) ?>
                 <?= $form->field($comments, 'text')->textarea(['rows' => 5, 'placeholder' => "Write Message"])->label(false)?>
                 <?= Html2::submitButton('Post Comment', ['class' => 'btn send-btn']) ?>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['id']` и `request->post()` немного сбивает с толку.........`Я вардампил атрибуты которые приходят в модель, там всё что надо, кроме поля name` - так добавьте в модель поле...... откройте `gii`, сгенерируйте модель, посмотрите в чем отличие от существующей... добавьте нужное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, ваше поле name не сетится через метод load, так как отсутствует в правилах валидации. Если вам не нежно валидировать это поле никак, то в описании правил используйте SafeValidator:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['name', 'safe']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Во втором проекте была та же самая проблема. Уже делал все что мог, тут увидел Ваш метод - действительно сработало. Странно.. Спасибо)

Comment: Но хотел бы спросить таки. У меня ранее был создан проект, я через Gii создал CRUD, и было всё тоже самое. Я даже ради интереса скопировал в новый проект но всё равно не работало, а в старом работало. И при этом в той модели не было ничего типо safe в правилах валидации. Так почему же тут не работает без safe, а там работает? Или всё равно, safe или другое какое-либо, главное что бы были правила валидации для этого поля? Я думал правила валидации не обязательны

Comment: Обязательны. Если у вас нет правил валидации, то есть вы никак не проверяете входное значение, то фреймворк не считает этот атрибут безопасным.

Comment: Большое спасибо!)